# Convert WebHistory Item array to String Array in Xamarin Android Webview

Tags: android, arrays, xamarin, webview, history

I have an activity that is supposed to display the list of visited URLs by user, I fetch the history using WebViewHistory item logic and populate the data into my layout with ListView Array Adapter. Except that the WebViewHistory item is displayed in this machine language that can't be understood by humans. One list for instance has the history as `p7@5561337`.I just need code i can use to convert the WebViewHistoryItem array to human readable string array

```
  class History : AppCompatActivity 
    {
        ListView listView;
        WebView mywebview;
         protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         mywebview = Internet.webview;
            WebHistoryItem[] webHistories = new WebHistoryItem[size];
             int size = webviewHistory.Size;
            for(int i = 0; i <size; i++)
            {
                webHistories[i] = webviewHistory.GetItemAtIndex(i);
            }
     //Locate listview in Resource Layout
           histView = (ListView)FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mainlistview);
      //populate webview history item into listview
           histView.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, 
            Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,webHistories);
        }
    
    }
```

I defined webview in the previous Activity as both static and public letting me access its instance in this activity, how can i convert `webhistories` array to `string`Thanks so much for help

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.webkit.webhistoryitem.url?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: Thanks Jason, am going to try that and see if i will get the history url populated to my listview...

Comment: Am using this but am still getting the storage pointer of the urls, please help     ```string[] histo = new string[] { webviewHistory.GetItemAtIndex(0).Url.ToString()};```

Comment: Hey jason i got something, I can get the Title of the current url via this method ``` string[] my=new string[] { webviewHistory.CurrentItem.Title } ;```, Can we reason it out from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i got something, I can get the Title of the current url via this method  `string[] my=new string[] { webviewHistory.CurrentItem.Title } ;`, Can we reason it out from here?

Yes.

> Am using this but am still getting the storage pointer of the urls, please help string[] histo = new string[] { webviewHistory.GetItemAtIndex(0).Url.ToString()};

You can use `List` to contains history record. I create an model called `VisitHistroy`. And show the title and url at the sametime in the listview like this GIF.

[image]

Here is my completely code.

```
     [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        EditText editText1;
        WebView webView1;
        ListView listView1;
        Button button1;
        public delegate void OnLinkSelectedHandler(string url);
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

             editText1= FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
             webView1 = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
             listView1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
             button1= FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;
           
            webView1.LoadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
            webView1.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView1.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient(this.ISVistedSoLink));
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // throw new System.NotImplementedException();

            WebBackForwardList wbfl = webView1.CopyBackForwardList();
            int size = wbfl.Size;
            var webHistories = new WebHistoryItem[wbfl.Size];
            List<VisitHistroy> strs = new List<VisitHistroy>();
          

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                //  histo = new string[] { wbfl.GetItemAtIndex(0).Url.ToString() };

                strs.Add(new VisitHistroy() { Title = wbfl.GetItemAtIndex(i).Title.ToString(), Url = wbfl.GetItemAtIndex(i).Url.ToString() });
                
            }
            //SimpleAdapter(Context? context, IList<IDictionary<string, object>>? data, int resource, string[]? from, int[]? to);
            listView1.Adapter = new MyAdapter(this, strs);
        }

        public void ISVistedSoLink(string url)
        {
            editText1.Text = url;
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    internal class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<VisitHistroy>
    {
        private MainActivity mainActivity;
        private List<VisitHistroy> strs;

        public MyAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<VisitHistroy> strs):base()
        {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            this.strs = strs;
        }

        public override VisitHistroy this[int position] => strs[position];

        public override int Count => strs.Count;

      

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
           return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = strs[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = mainActivity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Itemlayout, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemTitle).Text = item.Title;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.itemurl).Text = item.Url;
           
            return view;
        }
    }

    public class VisitHistroy
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is custom item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/abc_font_family_title_material"
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"/>
     <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/abc_font_family_title_material"
        android:id="@+id/itemurl"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Get"
        android:id="@+id/button1"/>
    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dip"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
         />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hey you defined variable ```webhistories```but you didnt use it, can you explain why  that is?

Comment: Am getting this error  Cant convert from ```Browser.History``` to ```Browser.MainActivity``` on this line   ```listView1.Adapter = new MyAdapter(this,strs);```